# possibility to do type/data conversion of data returned by ria services?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

My service returns an byte array, which I have to convert to an 'animated gif' (using [imagetools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) since silverlight doesn't support it yet)

I was wondering, is it possible to insert some code at the client, where I can do the conversion before the actual object is returned to whatever it is binded against?

On the server side, the queries can be customized before it is sent over the wire. I'm asking for the exact opposite, can I do some on the fly conversions the moment they get of the wire and before they are returned to the controls.

If I'm overthinking this and there is a smarter/better/easier way to do it, I'm all for such an answer as well

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution where the conversion happens during the binding process:[Retreiving and saving images from SQL server using RIA services](http://www.rhlopez.com/blog/post/2010/02/16/Retrieving-and-saving-images-from-SQL-Server-using-RIA-Services-and-Silverlight.aspx)